# Could not open input file: artisan when running php artisan serv

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to run an existing laravel project in my new windows.
when I try

```
php artisan serv
```

in my project directory, it says

> Could not open input file: artisan

I even updated composer

how to configure my old project anyway?

Comment: try to run localhost/project-name

Comment: on which location (inside the project folder or outside the project folder) you are running the php artisan serve command ? Please check spelling of serve

Comment: in my laravel project directory. i installed a new windows recently and today i installed composer in my new windows

Comment: but when i'm trying to run my old project from previous windows artisan command does not recognized.

Comment: Please confirm whether composer installed or not by composer -v command.

Comment: Composer version 1.8.4 2019-02-11 10:52:10

Comment: it is already installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run proper command on laravel project root directory:

```
php artisan serve
```

Comment: artisan was not recognized. But now it is.